# Is the Busy Beaver with n states also the busiest Turing machine (counted in steps) with n states?

Tags: turing-machines, busy-beaver

Based on the Busy Beaver rules (2 letter alphabet, 2-way unbounded tape, program must halt, etc) I was wondering if the Busy Beaver for each n is also the program that does the most steps, or if there are other programs that do more steps but produce less output.

Any references appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Wikipedia page for the Busy Beaver game (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) there is a section about "Maximum Shifts Function" which seems to answer your question.

Comment: Rereading that section it says that S(n) (maximum shifts) and Σ(n) are known or bounded for n 1-6 but it doesn't say it is proven for the machine with the largest Σ to have the largest S. Just that S >= Σ

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood your question originally. I guess you could check, for n = 2,3,4 if there is a machine that achieves $\Sigma(n)$ and $S(n)$ since those values are known. But my guess is that it is not known in general.